# IOS 5 Application Updates in separate thread

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm creating an app that needs to be updated periodically (for chats, notifications, contact detail changes, etc). Xcode 4.2 IOS 5 
I'm using sudzc generated code to consume the webservices. Those method calls are async as expected. I thought i could call all the update webservices within an NSOperation. However, i've discovered that the lifetime of an NSOperation is too short for any handler methods to be called. I've seen some "solutions" to that problem...but none them use the sudzc soap client generated classes. I also need to call the set of webservices periodically (like every 10 or so seconds). 
So basically i need to call the webservices periodically and in a separate thread from the main thread. I'll also need to use the return values to update UI's.

Can someone please give me some advice.

Thanks :)